# How to make vistime plot in R customizable

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, gantt-chart, vistime

I want to be able to click one bar of the gantt chart created in vistime plot to see the details of all the related events of that category. Is that customization possible with vistime? Also, how can I add a vertical line in the plot indicating the current date like other gantt charts have?

Comment: this should be possible for all outputs `hc_vistime()` (highcharter), `gg_vistime()` (ggplot) and `vistime()` (Plotly), which one are you trying?

Comment: Answer to the vertical line question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64900032/6498638