# Legend when adding a vertical line to vistime plot

Tags: r, plotly, vistime

I have a timeline I've made using vistime, and I've added a vertical line at a particular date.  Here's the example:

```
 curr_year <- 2017
 data <- read.csv(text="event,group,start,end,color
                       Phase 1,Project,2016-12-22,2016-12-23,#c8e6c9
                       Phase 2,Project,2016-12-23,2016-12-29,#a5d6a7
                       Phase 3,Project,2016-12-29,2017-01-06,#fb8c00
                       Phase 4,Project,2017-01-06,2017-02-02,#DD4B39
                       Room 334,Team 1,2016-12-22,2016-12-28,#DEEBF7
                       Room 335,Team 1,2016-12-28,2017-01-05,#C6DBEF
                       Room 335,Team 1,2017-01-05,2017-01-23,#9ECAE1
                       Group 1,Team 2,2016-12-22,2016-12-28,#E5F5E0
                       Group 2,Team 2,2016-12-28,2017-01-23,#C7E9C0
                       3-200,category 1,2016-12-25,2016-12-25,#1565c0
                       3-330,category 1,2016-12-25,2016-12-25,#1565c0
                       3-223,category 1,2016-12-28,2016-12-28,#1565c0
                       3-225,category 1,2016-12-28,2016-12-28,#1565c0
                       3-226,category 1,2016-12-28,2016-12-28,#1565c0
                       3-226,category 1,2017-01-19,2017-01-19,#1565c0
                       3-330,category 1,2017-01-19,2017-01-19,#1565c0
                       1-217.0,category 2,2016-12-27,2016-12-27,#90caf9
                       4-399.7,moon rising,2017-01-13,2017-01-13,#f44336
                       8-831.0,sundowner drink,2017-01-17,2017-01-17,#8d6e63
                       9-984.1,birthday party,2016-12-22,2016-12-22,#90a4ae
                       F01.9,Meetings,2016-12-26,2016-12-26,#e8a735
                       Z71,Meetings,2017-01-12,2017-01-12,#e8a735
                       B95.7,Meetings,2017-01-15,2017-01-15,#e8a735
                       T82.7,Meetings,2017-01-15,2017-01-15,#e8a735")

data <- as.data.frame(data)                               
p <- vistime(data)
pb <- plotly_build(p)
add_segments(p, 
             x = curr_year, 
             xend = curr_year, 
             y = pb$x$layout$yaxis$range[1], 
             yend = pb$x$layout$yaxis$range[2], 
             color = I("red"))
```

How do I add a text to the legend, for the line added?  Right now, it just says "trace 21".

[image]

Comment: Try adding `name = "new text"` as an argument to `add_segments`

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  How about changing the width of the line?  I can't find any documentation on this, which is kind of unfortunate..

Comment: Try adding `line = list(width = 25)` as an argument

Comment: Looks like there's a 'size' parameter

Comment: That works too...

Comment: Thanks man!  Appreciate the help.

Comment: sorry one more stupid question.. is there a method to get rid of those grid lines on the chart, or to change their appearance (i.e. color transparency, etc).  Again, I have really struggled to find good documentation for vistime.

Comment: I don't know...but you could try piping the result to `layout`, and something like `%>% layout(xaxis = list(showgrid = F), yaxis = list(showgrid = F))`...but that won't get rid of all lines...

Comment: you mean piping pb (the output of plotly_build function)?

Comment: order may not matter, but would add after `add_segments (...) %>%`

Comment: Thank you for the help, that seemed to do the trick, at least in terms of getting rid of the vertical lines.